# how does TensorFlow handle the differentials for L1 regularization?

Tags: tensorflow

it seems that you can just declare a cost function by tf.abs() and then pass it down to auto-gradient generation (see https://github.com/nfmcclure/tensorflow_cookbook/blob/master/03_Linear_Regression/04_Loss_Functions_in_Linear_Regressions/04_lin_reg_l1_vs_l2.py)

. but we know abs() is not differentiable.

how is this done in Tensorflow? does it just randomly throw a number in [-1,1] ?

if someone could please point me to the implementation that would be great. Thanks!

(I looked for tensorflow.py in the git, but it does not even exist)

Answer (score 6):

`f(x) = abs(x)` is differentiable everywhere, except at `x=0`. It derivative equals:

[image: abs derivative]

So the only question is how tensorflow implements derivative at `x=0`. You can check this manually:

```
import tensorflow as tf
x = tf.Variable(0.0)
y = tf.abs(x)
grad = tf.gradients(y, [x])[0]
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run(grad))
```

It prints `0.0`.

Answer (score 0):

A modified version, based on @standy 's answer.
Which you can modify the function yourself:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
x = tf.Variable(0.0)
y = tf.where(tf.greater(x, 0), x+2, 2)  # The piecewise-defined function here is：y=2 (x<0), y=x+2 (x>=0)
grad = tf.gradients(y, [x])[0]
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run(grad))
```

I would recommend a post of mine, visulized L1 & L2 Regularization with echarts:
https://simzhou.com/en/posts/2021/cross-entropy-loss-visualized/